# Better fluency in second language than native.

Tags: language-competence

What are ways, patterns of living in native speaking country, where you are thinking and talking better in second language?
I am trying to translate words, sentences which is difficult, also don't have too much opportunities to talk, since i am talking in native, which is beeing boring and misunderstood, so it leads to social exclusion, and that is. 
I am worried to go abroad to foreign country, but i would like to have emotional bond with someone, because i can't have emotional bonds in polish, rather. 
Is this better to try learning native, or rather go further way, where i feel better? 
Or are there any places even in internet, where i can talk chat with people talking english? You know i am young person, i don't want to have boring life with a watch in hand and without emotions. You know, they said - learn, so i learned a lot - for now i sam very sad with these emotional bonds, as i am watching my neighbours having great conversations and laughing and a lot of people i want to talk to, but i can't because of this paradox. Is there any option instead of leaving country? no one knows answers, so maybe here i will find a solution for this.

How it happened - i read a lot of literature and articles in english for eight years, without leaving country. In brain explantation, i have associations of terms hidden in that language, dried in native. So i say in native sentence 1 and don't have association, but when i say in english, then i have five other associations or even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you have a problem in finding people to practice English with. There should be online chats for second language learners and communities where you can practice your English. 
The key is to keep practicing even if you practice it alone
I know it is hard but keep up the hard work.